# String to IO String (conditional mapM)

Tags: string, haskell, io

I'm working on my first Haskell tool (yay!) and I can't seem to find a solution to this problem. Most posts discuss converting a `String` to `IO String`, but I actually need to do the inverse, since I conditionally use `readFile` inside `mapM`.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but here's what I've got so far. This parses a source file (unrelated language) and replaces `#include` statements with the actual contents of the include file.

```
replaceInclude :: String -> IO String
replaceInclude contents = do
    f_lines <- mapM
            (\l ->
                if (isInfixOf "#include" l)
                then readFile (parseIncludePath l)
                else l -- !! This is the problem line !!
            )
            (lines contents)
   
    return (unlines f_lines)
```

As noted in comments, the problem line is the `else` statement, which returns a `String`, but `mapM` expects an `IO String`.

Any help would be appreciated, I believe I have to rewire my brain to do this the "haskell way" :)

Compile error :

```
* Couldn't match type `[]' with `IO'
  Expected type: IO String
    Actual type: [Char]
```

Comment: try `pure` / `return` (same thing)

Comment: @FrownyFrog Lol I just figured it out, so simple. Answered :)

Comment: If you `import Data.Traversable`, you can write `f_lines <- for (lines contents) $ \l -> if ....`. `for` is roughly `mapM` with the arguments flipped.

Comment: @chi ty! Can I ask, I've seen `$` and `.` used in many places but haven't got to their meaning yet, would you have a quick explanation for them?

Comment: `$` is a function application operator: `f $ x` means `f x`. It's mainly used to avoid parentheses in certain cases, e.g. `f (g x y)` becomes `f $ g x y`. Instead, `.` is function composition: `f . g` means `(\x -> f (g x))`. If you are a beginner, don't worry too much about them -- it's easy to misuse them and obtain errors at first. Above, I suggested using `$` for the last argument of `for` since it's multi-line and avoiding parentheses there looks nice.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, thanks again

Comment: As a general rule, one should reframe any desire to take "a thing" out of "a monad" (like getting a `String` from an `IO String`) as a desire to put something (possibly something else) _into_ the monad. This is because the `Monad` typeclass provides a handy method for doing the latter (called `return`) while intentionally making the former _impossible_ (except by cheating). Take `do` notation for example: it superficially looks like a way to take something out of the monad, but in fact puts the entire computation _in_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG this was so simple, the solution is `else return l`.

For posterity and other beginners:
In Haskell, the `return` function creates an `IO` tagged type. It is such because reasons. This documentation in [A Gentle Introduction to Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/tutorial/io.html) is helpful and clear.

Comment: *In this context*, `return` produces an `IO String` value, because you are working with the `IO` monad. `return` works for all monads. Eg., `return 3 :: Maybe Int == Just 3`, `return 3 :: [Int] == [3]`, etc.